# corollary of the partition congruence

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integer-partitions, polynomial-congruences

I was going though the paper of Ramanujan entitled Some properties of p(n), the number of partitions of n (Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, XIX, 1919, 207 – 210). He states he found the proofs of p(5m + 4) ≡ 0 (mod 5)
and p(7m + 5) ≡ 0 (mod 7). Then he says p(35m + 19) ≡ 0 (mod 35) can be deduced as corollary. I did not get how do derive the third congruence p(35m + 19) ≡ 0 (mod 35) from p(5m + 4) ≡ 0 (mod 5) and p(7m + 5) ≡ 0 (mod 7), where p(n) unrestricted partition function.

Comment: Observe that $35m+19=5(7m+3)+4=7(5m+2)+5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given that

> $\dots$ he found the proofs of $p(5m + 4) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$
> and $p(7m + 5) \equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

The two statements can be written as

$$ n \equiv 4\pmod 5 \implies p(n)\equiv 0\pmod 5 $$

and

$$ n \equiv 5\pmod 7 \implies p(n)\equiv 0\pmod 7. $$

The [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)
applied to $n$ implies that the two conditions on $n$ combined are
equivalent to $ n \equiv 19\pmod{35}$. Similarly, the two conditions
on $p(n)$ combined are equivalent to $p(n)\equiv 0\pmod{35}$. The
conclusion is

$$  n \equiv 19\pmod{35} \implies p(n)\equiv 0\pmod{35}.$$